# Keep an html browser full screen on mac

Tags: html, macos, google-chrome, safari, max-msp-jitter

I'm getting frustratingly stuck on a quite simple problem. I run an html slideshow. I need it to be full screen (no toolbar, no topbar) at every moment.

In the background, a lot is getting done however. I got an app (Canon EOS Utility) that is regularly activated by applescript. Here is my problem : **activating this program automatically quits the full screen mode (or presentation mode) in the browser. How can I stop this?**

The full screen mode seems to be part of OS X (Mission Control) - it behaves the same way with every browser.

I tried [Afloat 2.0](http://afloat.en.softonic.com/mac) but this doesn't hide the toolbar and topbar.

Have a clue to solve this?

BTW I'm using Max/MSP for background process, if anything can be done with that.

Thanks !

M

Comment: This is not a [programming question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and therefore is outside the scope of this forum.

Comment: Can't you use ⌘ + [Shift] + F on Chrome?

Comment: Well, actually, this might be overpassed by "programming" - if you consider applescript programming. This is the path I'm searching right now. It might also be done by JS on the html itself, but I doubt it.

⌘ + [Shift] + F on Chrome works indeed - but the point is I can't stay in that full screen mode if an app is launched or activated in the background.

Anyway... still searching, thanks for your replies !

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I’ve solved my problem by not solving it !

The "EOS Utility" software, which was triggered by applescript, needed to be "activated" to work. That caused fullscreen to quit.

I’ve found this jem : gphoto2 (http://photolifetoys.blogspot.ca/2012/08/control-your-camera-with-gphoto2-via.html)
It can be used to tether a whole bunch of cameras via command lines. This, of course, doesn’t change the OS display.

So the full screen stays… !

This is good enough for now, for me… Just replying for the record, if it can help anyone !